# Как обойти задержку в 1 сек на неактивной вкладке webkit?

Tags: javascript, html, html5

Как обойти ограничение в виде задержки в 1 секунд, при неактивной вкладке браузера webkit?

Даже с worker-а сообщения накапливаются и с интервалом в ~1 секунду высылаются сразу пачкой.

### Основная цель — сделать максимально быстрый(>200fps) обмен сообщениями основного потока с worker-ом, вне зависимости от того, активна вкладка или нет.

Попробую сформулировать вопрос по другому и добавить наглядный код.

Есть тестовый воркер:

```
onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
    var msg = rawMsg.data;

    msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage";
    msg.times.push( performance.now() );

    postMessage(msg);
}

var sequenceNum = 0;

setInterval(function() {
    var msg = {state:"", times: [], sequenceNum: sequenceNum++};

    msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval";
    msg.times.push( performance.now() );

    postMessage(msg);
}, 100);
```

Есть тестовый код основного потока:

```
    var worker = new Worker( 'js/test-worker.js' );

worker.onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
    var msg = rawMsg.data;

    switch( msg.state ) {
        case "worker-THREAD:setInterval":
            msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main:thread:onmessage";
            msg.times.push( performance.now() );

            worker.postMessage(msg);
            break;

        case "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage":
            show(msg);
            break;
    }
}

var MAX_SHOW_COUNT = 100;
var showCount = -1;
var lastSequenceNum = -1;
function show(msg) {
    msg.times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val / 1e3 });

    if ( lastSequenceNum + 1 !== msg.sequenceNum ) {
        alert("error sequence");
    }
    lastSequenceNum++;


    var ping = msg.times[2] - msg.times[0];

    var isBad = ( ping > 0.01 );

    var fx = 3;

    var times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val.toFixed(3) });
    ping = ping.toFixed(fx);

    console.log('#' + msg.sequenceNum + ' [ ' + times.join(', ') + ' ] ' + ping + (isBad?' BAD!!!': ''));
}
```

Каждые 0,1 сек из воркера идет пакет в основной поток, оттуда обратно в воркер и потом снова в основной поток, потом все выводится в консоль.
На старте и в каждом onmessage ставится время.

Структура выводимой в консоль записи:

```
#порядковый номер пакета [время старта(каллбек setInterval) , время приема в основном потоке, время снова в воркере] дельта времени(пинг).
```

```js
var worker_Code = `
 onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
  var msg = rawMsg.data;
 
  msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage";
  msg.times.push( performance.now() );
  
  postMessage(msg);
 }
 
 var sequenceNum = 0;
 
 setInterval(function() {
  var msg = {state:"", times: [], sequenceNum: sequenceNum++};
  
  msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval";
  msg.times.push( performance.now() );

  postMessage(msg);
 }, 100);
`;

var worker = new Worker( window.URL.createObjectURL( new Blob( [worker_Code] ) ) );

worker.onmessage = function(rawMsg) {
 var msg = rawMsg.data;
 
 switch( msg.state ) {
  case "worker-THREAD:setInterval":
   msg.state = "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main:thread:onmessage";
   msg.times.push( performance.now() );
   
   worker.postMessage(msg);
   break;

  case "worker-THREAD:setInterval=>main-THREAD:onmessage=>worker-THREAD:onmessage":
   show(msg);
   break;
 }
}

var MAX_SHOW_COUNT = 100;
var showCount = -1;
var lastSequenceNum = -1;
function show(msg) {
 msg.times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val / 1e3 });

 if ( lastSequenceNum + 1 !== msg.sequenceNum ) {
  alert("error sequence");
 }
 lastSequenceNum++;

 
 var ping = msg.times[2] - msg.times[0];
 
 var isBad = ( ping > 0.01 );
 
 var fx = 3;
 
 var times = msg.times.map(function(val) { return val.toFixed(3) });
 ping = ping.toFixed(fx);

 console.log('#' + msg.sequenceNum + ' [ ' + times.join(', ') + ' ] ' + ping + (isBad?' BAD!!!': ''));
}
```

### или вот jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/03pfwmt9/

Как видно если вкладка не активна, Onmessage основного потока ждет 1 сек, а потом сбрасывает разом все накопившиеся сообщения, что в моей задаче(игра) является не приемлемым. 
Как починить?

Comment: если вкладка неактивна, то зачем показывать в игре что то в это время ?

Comment: Это онлайн игра. Можно было бы все в воркере сделать, но там не доступе webrtc. Потому нужно отсылать иноформацию в основной поток, (пакеты для webrtc).